# printf prints character instead of digit for %d specifier

Tags: c, xcode, printf, specifier

On xcode c project, the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int* pi = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *pi = 5;
    printf("*pi: %d\n", *pi);
    free(pi);



    return 0;
}
```

prints 't' , instead of 5, although I explicitly included the %specifier, that according to spec should print the signed decimal integer. I would expect the '%c' specifier would print that. What is going on?

[image]

Comment: I cannot spot any mistake making the program undefined, implementation-defined, or semantically wrong. Except maybe the cast of the `malloc` return value.

Comment: But note that Pi does not equal `5` for real and is not an integer. ;-)

Comment: I use standard unmodified unaltered Xcode, this is my first project and almost freshly installed el capitan as OS. No inclusion of any libraries.

Comment: running correct on ubuntu x86 - output is "*pi: 5" - please recompile, maybe you have old code.

Comment: http://ideone.com/O9qE6O Runs fine here as well.

Comment: Try adding `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: I am running it on 2015 macbook pro retina, i did rerun in several times, and even rebooted

Comment: @DraifKroneg; I too ran on 2015 macbook pro retina display and its output display `5`.

Comment: including <stdlib.h> did not help, it is still t

Comment: Add an additional printf to the code. If you don't see it, you're not running the program you think you are.

Comment: i do not have any other code - this is my first project in Xcode

Comment: But the output in the screen shot doesn't seem to match the code. Output shows "Hello World" but there is no such print in the code. And code has "hi" which is not shown in the output. So it appears it could be an IDE issue rather than a code issue.

Comment: right click on your file that contains your desired code to input and you should be able to see a run option. click it and see. 

IDE usually start off with a hello world script to start of the user and check correct compilation.

Comment: in C, do not cast the value returned from `malloc()` as that returned value has the type `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.   Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: the posted code fails to compile.  The compiler will output a message about the implicit declaration of function malloc() and function free().  this statement: `#include <stdlib.h>` needs to be added.  after correcting the code, the function outputs: `*pi: 5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C dynamic memory allocation functions are defined in **stdlib.h** header.

If you add the 'standard library' to your code, it should run without any errors.

Also, malloc() returns a null pointer when it fails to allocate the space requested. So, you should make sure that what you received is not NULL by using a simple if-else block.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int* pi = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));

    if(pi==NULL){
       printf("Malloc Failed!");
       return -1;
    }
    else{
        *pi = 5;
        printf("*pi: %d\n", *pi);
        free(pi);
        return 0;
    }

}
```

The code block above gives the intended result *pi: 5.

Hope this helps,

**Reference:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation

Comment: So does the code in original post, without a single change.